# Using beautiful soup and scrapy error give me that error refer before assignment

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data but they give me error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd3' referenced before assignment`  how I  can solve these error any solution please suggest me I search many solution but I cannot find any solution that help me if you have any solution then suggest me  these is page link https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abaewicz-agnieszka-51004

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }


    def parse(self, response):
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        tra = soup.find_all('td', class_='icon_link')
        for links in tra:
            for link in links.find_all('a', href=True):
                comp = link['href']
                yield Request(comp, callback=self.parse_book)
     
    
    def parse_book(self, response):
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        details = soup.find_all('div', class_='line_list_K')
        for detail in details:
            try:
                status = detail.find(
                    'span', string='Status:').findNext('div').getText()
            except:
                pass

            try:
                d1 = detail.find('span', string='Data wpisu w aktualnej izbie na listę adwokatów:').findNext(
                    'div').getText()
            except:
                pass
            
            try:
                d3 = detail.find('span', string='Ostatnie miejsce wpisu:').findNext(
                    'div').getText()
            except:
                pass
            
            
            try:
                d4 = detail.find('span', string='Stary nr wpisu:').findNext(
                    'div').getText()
            except:
                pass
            
            
            try:
                d5 = detail.find('span', string='Zastępca:').findNext(
                    'div').getText()
            except:
                pass
            
            yield{
               'status':status,
               "d1":d1,
               "d3":d3,
               "d4":d4,
               "d5":d5
               }
```

Comment: any solution for these

Answer (score 0):

You have the assignment to `d3` inside a `try/except`. If this gets an error, the assignment won't happen. If it happens on the first iteration, the variable is unset; if it happens on a later iteration, you won't get an error, but you'll put the previous value of `d3` in the dictionary.

You should assign a default value in the `except:` block.

```
            try:
                d3 = detail.find('span', string='Ostatnie miejsce wpisu:').findNext(
                    'div').getText()
            except:
                d3 = ''
```

You should also do this for all the other variable assignments.

If you always get this error, you're probably looking for the wrong thing in `detail.find()`. You should figure out the root cause and fix it.